# jspdf x/y position vs css left:top fixed position

Tags: javascript, css, pdf-generation, jspdf

Using [JsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to generate a pdf which matches my styling in html/css.

I'm rendering three items (item one, two and three) in html like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/nwyabsud/

```
        <img style="position:fixed;top:1cm;height:40mm;width:80mm;" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/37/Denny%27s_logo.svg/1280px-Denny%27s_logo.svg.png" class="img-responsive center-block" />
        <div style="position:fixed;top:5cm;left:10.5cm;">
            Item One
        </div>
        <div style="position:fixed;top:6cm;left:10.5cm">
            Item Two
        </div>
        <div style="position:fixed;top:7cm;left:10.5cm">
            Item Three
        </div>
```

and rendering three elements in jspdf like this.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'mm', 'a4');
doc.addImage(this.config.header.img, // Image in base64 encoding
  this.config.header.format, // e.g. "JPEG" "PNG"
  this.config.pageCenter, // @x-axis: position of image from left                
  10, // @y-axis: position of image from top
  80, // @width: width of image                 
  40); // @height: height of image

doc.setFontSize(10);
doc.text(105, 50, 'Item One');
doc.text(105, 60, 'Item Two');
doc.text(105, 70, 'Item Three');
```

But! They are coming out at slightly different heights. Can anyone spot why these are not coming out at the same height?

[image]